# V8 - Casting args.Data() back to void pointer

Tags: c++, v8

Currently I am binding a function using the following:

```
global->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "print", NewStringType::kNormal).ToLocalChecked(), FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, V8Instance::js_print));
```

With the function:

```
static void js_print(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &args);
```

implementation:

```
void V8Instance::js_print(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < args.Length(); i++) {
        v8::HandleScope handle_scope(args.GetIsolate());
        v8::String::Utf8Value str(args[i]);
        std::cout << *str << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

However I want my js_print function to have access to a variable which is a member of the class V8Instance. Does V8 have something like being able to use `boost::bind(&Class::function, this, ...)` that lets me bind member functions, or is there some way to pass the variable I need by reference/pointer to `js_print` every time it is called?

## Update

I have found out that I can pass a pointer to my class using the data parameter of `FunctionTemplate::New`:

```
Local<External> self = External::New(isolate, (void *) this);
global->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "print", NewStringType::kNormal).ToLocalChecked(), FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, V8Instance::js_print, self));
```

I can access this in my `js_print` function using `args.Data()` but this returns `Local<Value>` object which I'm not sure how to cast back to `void *` and then back to my class pointer, `V8Instance *`. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may wrap a C++ object into a corresponding `v8::ObjectTemplate` and set accessors for it, as described in [V8 Embedder's Guide](https://developers.google.com/v8/embed).

To wrap a C++ class (i.e. to use many C++ instances of this C++ class from JavaScript) you will need to create V8 `FunctionTemplate` as a JS constructor function for the wrapped class which will store pointer to a C++ object in a V8 `Object` instance, and to set V8 function callbacks for desired member functions in the that class. These callbacks should unwrap C++ object from V8 object and to call appropriate member function for the unwrapped object.

This approach leads to writing a lot of boilerplate code. Node.js allows to inherit C++ class from [`node::ObjectWrap`](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_wrapping_c_objects) in a native addon.

I've also created [v8pp](https://github.com/pmed/v8pp) library that binds C++ classes, functions, and lambdas in non-intrusive way, without inheritance.

There are several similar libraries exist. But, as I know, they are outdated and don't support new V8 versions.

**Update.** To get `V8Instance*` from external data you need to cast `args.Data()` value to `v8::External` and then get pointer from that external value and cast it to `V8Instance*`. Something like this:

```
void V8Instance::js_print(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &args)
{
    v8::Local<v8::External> ext = args.Data().As<v8::External>();
    V8Instance* self = static_cast<V8Instance*>(ext->Value());
    ....
}
```

Comment: I asked on the v8 google group and apparently I can just pass a pointer to my class as data in the `FunctionTemplate` (3rd argument.) I've figured out how to do this using the following:

`Local<External> self = External::New(isolate, (void *) this);`
and then passing `self` as the third argument but I can't figure out how to convert `args.Data()` (in `js_print`) back to `V8Instance *`

Comment: Thanks, yeah that's what I was looking for. Marked correct

Comment: There is a slight mistake in your code btw, `<v8::Extneral>` should be `<v8:External>` and `ext.Value()` should be `ext->Value()`

Comment: Thanks, fixed the answer.